# Javascript: calculate the total sum of all the object values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects as the following;

```
[{"A":"34"},{"B":"13"},{"C":"35"},{"D":"74"}]
```

If the key is A, it's value has to be multiply by 30,B by 10,C by 5,D by 2. I would like to calculate the total sum after the multiplication;

```
34*30 + 13*10 + 35*5 + 74*2
```

Is there a way to achieve this other than an if/else statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the array, and get the key / value pair by destructuring the array produce by calling  `Object.entries()` on the each item. Get the value of the key, multiply by current value, and add to the accumulator.

```js
const multi = { A: 30, B: 10, C: 5, D: 2 }

const fn = arr => 
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const [[k, v]] = Object.entries(item)
    
    return acc + multi[k] * v
  }, 0)

const arr = [{"A":"34"},{"B":"13"},{"C":"35"},{"D":"74"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Same thinking and same solution. I saw your solution after I posted mine.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let input = [{"A": "34"}, {"B": "13"}, {"C": "35"}, {"D": "74"}];
let multiply = {A: 30, B: 10, C: 5, D: 2};

let result = input.reduce((sum, v) => 
        sum + Object.values(v)[0] * multiply[Object.keys(v)[0]], 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const arr = [{ A: "34" }, { B: "13" }, { C: "35" }, { D: "74" }];
const multiplier = {
  A: 30,
  B: 10,
  C: 5,
  D: 2,
};

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(curr);
  return acc + multiplier[key] * parseInt(value);
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an dictionary to get the number with which the value should be multiplied as shown :
{"A":30, "B":13, "C":35, "D":74}

Now you can loop through your array of objects, and fetch the value from the dictionary using the key of the object:

```
const myArray = [{"A":"34"},{"B":"13"},{"C":"35"},{"D":"74"}]
const Nums = {"A":30, "B":10, "C":5, "D":2};
let Result = 0;

myArray.forEach((item)=>{
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  var temp= parseInt(item[key]);
  Result += temp*Nums[key];
})
console.log(Result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you map your values so that `"A" === 30`. But assuming you have a map:

```
const map = {
  "A": 30,
  "B": 10,
  "C": 5,
  "D": 2
}
```

`const array = [{"A":"34"},{"B":"13"},{"C":"35"},{"D":"74"}];`

Then in one line:

```
const outcome = array.map(element => map[Object.keys(element)[0]] * Object.values(element)[0]).reduce((acc, init) => acc + init, 0)
```